# Python SymPy solving linear system

Tags: python, sympy, importerror

I have Python 3.3.3 and SymPy 0.7.4.1, both in x64 version and installed locally on my computer. I am using PSPad as a configured editor for Python scripting.

**When using imports from library `sympy` in a module which should solve a set of three linear equations:**

```
from sympy import Matrix, solve_linear_system
from sympy.abc import x, y, z

def main():
    system = Matrix (((3,2,-1,1) ,(2,-2,4,-2),(-1,0.5,-1,0)))
    print(solve_linear_system(system, x, y,z))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**The editor PSPad console output returns the following:**

```
traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\GOODLU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\PSpad\securesafety_DISK_5GB\Programmation\linear system solve SYMPY.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sympy import Matrix,solve_linear_system   File "C:\Users\GOODLU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\PSpad\securesafety_DISK_5GB\Programmation\sympy.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sympy import var,Eq,solve ImportError: cannot import name var

Process completed, Exit Code 1.
Execution time: 00:00.134
```

**Actually, I am wondering myself heavily about those issues:**

1. Why, when typing the same thing, without an object `def main()`, and entered line by line in IDLE, everything is solved correctly, as: `{x: 1.00000000000000, y: -2.00000000000000, z: -2.00000000000000}`
2. Why, my PSPad file with object, having the same computation lines, doesn't work and returns errors?

In fact, I would like to use SymPy in normal python code and get computed results in a list or printed in console( .. as in IDLE). Just in order to avoid some annoying line-to-line IDLE manipulations, what should my code file look like?

Comment: Did you create the sympy.py file yourself ? what are the contents of the file?

Comment: Sunny, apparently I have created a distant FTP file named : linear system solve SYMPY.py // PSPAD have created a local copy : sympy.py . The whole content is above in the code section between from and if. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be that you have created a file named `sympy.py`, which has the same name as the `sympy` module.

Hence, in the `from sympy import ...` statement, your `sympy.py` is acting as the sympy module.

Try renaming the file to something else, like `sympy_programming_test.py` and let know if it works.

Comment: Great ! You have solved my problem !!!! So, there is a hint for everyone using ftp directories for editing code : beware of the "shadowed" temp file created by your editor !!! Actually, the python shell can be called twice and can literally mash up your computation !    Thank you, Sunny !!!!!!!!!!!!!.                   In fact, my code was sound, the bad turn was played by the shadowed temporary file !

Comment: You are very welcome :) And don't forget to accept the answer if the solution works :)